# Elastic Search issue with simple_query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I could not find a perfect solution for the following situation, hope someone could help here.

Suppose there are following documents present for type called "groups":

1. {"name": "Orders 1.0"}
2. {"name": "Reports & Analysis 1.0"}
3. {"name": "Rebates 1.0"}

When I search documents using below simple_query_string I am getting all three records instead of only one records (i.e. #1)

```
{
"size" : 20,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "should" : [
              {
                "simple_query_string" : {
                  "query" : "Orders 1.0*",
                  "fields" : [
                    "name^1.0"
                  ],
                  "flags" : -1,
                  "default_operator" : "or",
                  "lenient" : false,
                  "analyze_wildcard" : true,
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ],
            "disable_coord" : false,
            "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

I want only one record to be searched with name as Orders 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is this `"default_operator" : "or",`. 
I assume that the field `name` is an analyzed field. If it uses an analyzer, then it will be tokenized. The same goes for your input. So you have the following (for the standard analyzer)

- Orders 1.0 -> ["orders", "1.0"]
- Reports & Analysis 1.0 -> ["reports", "analysis", "1.0"]
- Rebates 1.0 -> ["rebates", "1.0"]

```
GET _analyze
{
  "analyzer": "standard",
  "text": ["Orders 1.0", "Reports & Analysis 1.0", "Rebates 1.0"]
}

{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "orders",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "1.0",
      "start_offset" : 7,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "reports",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "analysis",
      "start_offset" : 21,
      "end_offset" : 29,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "1.0",
      "start_offset" : 30,
      "end_offset" : 33,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "rebates",
      "start_offset" : 34,
      "end_offset" : 41,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "1.0",
      "start_offset" : 42,
      "end_offset" : 45,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 6
    }
  ]
}
```

Since the default operator is `OR`, it means that you need any of the analyzed tokens to match, not all. And since you've included `1.0` that is present on all of them, it matches all the documents. One solution is to change the default operator to `AND`

Comment: Thank you so much for you inputs and issue resolved after using AND